# Ambiguity in ANTLR grammar

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

AntlrWorks says that input `{'AND','OR'..'XOR'}` can be matched by two alternatives. Even with the graphical display, I could not figure out how the match happens! 
How on earth the ambiguity occurs in the grammar below, and is there a way to remove it?

```
grammar testg;

rul :  contains_expr    ;

contains_expr: 'CONTAINS' contains_expression
                  //'CONTAINS' contains_or
        ;

contains_expression :  primary  (('OR'|'AND'|'XOR') primary)*
       ;

primary options{backtrack = true;}
 : '(' contains_expression ')'
 | class_expression
 ;


class_expression :   simple_class_expr 
           | '(' simple_class_expr contains_expr ')'
           |( simple_class_expr contains_expr) 
        ;

simple_class_expr: identifier               // RM_TYPE_NAME
               | identifier identifier      // RM_TYPE_NAME variable
               | archetype_class_expr
         | versioned_class_expression
         | version_class_expression 
         // | identified_obj_expression     // need to be used once VersionedClassExpr is removed
        ;

identifier
    :   ID
    ;

archetype_class_expr
    :   '.ace'
    ;

versioned_class_expression
    :   '.vce'
    ;

version_class_expression
    :   '.vnce'
    ;

temp    :   
        ;


ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;
```

Comment: sarnold already explained why ANTLR is complaining about your grammar. If you still need help, I suggest that instead of posting only your grammar, you explain *what* language you're trying to write the grammar for. Could you give some examples and explain it? I have a hard time figuring out what language you're trying to parse by looking at your grammar alone.

Comment: Hi Bart. This is a snippet from Antlr port of openEHR's Archetype Query Language: http://www.openehr.org/wiki/display/spec/Archetype+Query+Language+Description The existing grammar was build with a LR parser generator, so I'm trying to get rid of left recursions and other things which are easy with a LR parser. I've managed to fix the problem I've asked here, thanks to both sarnold and syntactic predicates. I'll probably have to ask more Antlr questions though :)

Comment: Are you aware of the following grammar: http://www.openehr.org/wiki/display/spec/ANTLR+AQL+grammar ? (didn't test it!)

Comment: That grammar was uploaded to wiki today, and announcement arrived at openEHR lists a few hours ago :) I guess this is my lucky day...

Comment: and thanks for going through the trouble of letting me know about it!

Comment: That _is_ lucky! I didn't notice the date :). You're welcome, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you expect your grammar to parse `CONTAINS foo bar baz`?

`contains_expr` matches `CONTAINS`.

`contains_expression` "calls" `primary`.

`primary` "calls" `class_expression`.

`class_expression` "calls" `simple_class_expr`.

`simple_class_expr` can match: `identifier` or `identifier identifier`.

Thus I can see several possible parsings here; I've put individual `simple_class_expr` matches into parenthesis:

```
CONTAINS (foo bar) (baz)
CONTAINS (foo) (bar) (baz)
CONTAINS (foo) (bar baz)
```

I'm sorry to say that I'm new enough to parsing tools to not have suggestions how to *fix* this except wondering what `identifier identifier` might *mean*.